# How do I locate the angularjs error: unknown provider in a minified script?

Tags: angularjs

I get an error in console

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: aProvider <- a <- $httpBackend <- $http <- $compile
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.16/$injector/unpr?p0=aProvider%20%3C-%20a%20%3C-%20%24httpBackend%20%3C-%20%24http%20%3C-%20%24compile
```

The script file is generated by grunt task `ngmin` followed by `uglify`

I can understand it could be caused by an incorrect minification. The questions is how do I find out **which line in which file** is not minified correctly?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't uglify file, Haven't the same error?

If you have the error, make sure the dependency is defined and spelled correctly.

Else, you could to download and use the angular minified from the web https://angularjs.org/
or you could use bower to download and specific version, all of them include the minified file.